# Data binding when model objects lacks some properties

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, mvvm, extension-methods, data-binding

In a MVVM scenario the model 'Impegni' is created from a database table using linq2sql.
A Wpf form displays all the 'Impegni' fields and this is achieved binding the object exposed by the viewmodel, ImpegnoSelezionato of type 'Impegni', to the DataContext of the grid which contains all the other UI controls. 
Unfortunately in the form some more fields need to be displayed and part of them may be directly derived from the model (for example one of them is a boolean comparison between two model fields). 
The first solution is to expose other properties in the viewmodel.
Due to the DataContext set on the Grid every new control which shows the added properties on the viewmodel needs something like:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=  {x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ActiveWorkspace}"
```

which is a very odd syntax for me and I cannot believe there is no something simpler to use.

The second idea I had is to create some method extensions for the 'Impegni' model. Those methods wouldn't need any parameter and would be equivalent to the getter methods of properties.
After some net surfing it seems the only way to bind a control to a method instead of a property is to use an ObjectDataProvider  and I couldn't find out what to write in the 'ObjectType="{x:Type ??}'

The third idea is to regenerate the model with some more properties, but as I said before it comes from a dfatabase table using linq2sql: I'm a newbe and I don't know if I can add extra fields which are not on the database table.

So at the time I write only the first idea has proven to be working but I would like something a bit cleaner.
Any suggestions ?

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: The syntax in the first option is perfectly fine

Comment: I had to search for hours before finding that curious way to override the DataContext. I would have expected I could achieve that goal (restore the DataContext of a particular component to its default) in a simpler way.

Comment: You're just looking for "ActiveworkSpace" in the ViewModel of the parent window. There's nothing wrong about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten that binding a fair bit, nothing unclean about it.

Original:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                        AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
         Path=DataContext.ActiveWorkspace}
```

Minimal:

```
{Binding DataContext.ActiveWorkspace,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}
```

This does a few things:

1. Use markup extension constructors. The first unnamed argument is passed as constructor parameter, in a [binding that is the path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx) so `Path=` can be dropped.
2. Use implicit conversion to `Type`. As the property `AncestorType` is already of type `Type` the `x:Type` is redundant
3. Drop properties which are set implicitly, in this case setting the `AncestorType` also sets the `Mode` to `FindAncestor`. (You could also use a constructor here to drop the `Mode=` by the way)

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution for binding to 'derived' model values would be to use [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)s in conjunction with multi-value converters ([IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

For the third idea I found this helpful post:
[How to correctly add a runtime-calculated, non-persistant read-only property to a LinqToSQL data class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132920/how-to-correctly-add-a-runtime-calculated-non-persistant-read-only-property-to)
I can easily add the properties I missed to the model so this solution is the cleanest I can think.